# Getting client IP and then city name from it

Tags: php, ip

Here I am trying to get IP of user when he click login button on my page. I want to get `city` name finally from IP.

```
function get_client_ip() {
     $ipaddress = '';
     if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
         $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
     else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
         $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
         $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
     else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
         $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
         $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
     else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
         $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     else
         $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

     return $ipaddress; 
}
```

Is there any better and faster way other then above one?

And then to get city,

```
$ip = get_client_ip();
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
echo $details->city;
```

Comment: You can download ip ranges related to cities and store them in db, so you can test the ip against the range in your local db, which will be faster for executing, but I don't think the effort worths

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once("userip/ip.codehelper.io.php");
require_once("userip/php_fast_cache.php");

$_ip = new ip_codehelper();

$real_client_ip_address = $_ip->getRealIP();
$visitor_location       = $_ip->getLocation($real_client_ip_address);

$guest_ip   = $visitor_location['IP'];
$guest_country = $visitor_location['CountryName'];
$guest_city  = $visitor_location['CityName'];
$guest_state = $visitor_location['RegionName'];

echo "IP Address: ". $guest_ip. "<br/>";
echo "Country: ". $guest_country. "<br/>";
echo "State: ". $guest_state. "<br/>";
echo "City: ". $guest_city. "<br/>";

?>
```

for details take a look here http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/visitor-location-in-php

Comment: If you are using a library, shouldn't you be providing the link, where to download it?

Comment: there is a download link in above link